# Can I change different logo for different pages in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I want to change different logo for each different pages in drupal and I also want to hide logo for some pages too.How can I do that?I've already search possible answers and I didn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated by MilanG, logo is rendered in your page template (default `page.tpl.php` or theme suggestion) using `$logo` variable. This variable is set in [`template_preprocess_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7.x), and the best way to change it is to use the same preprocess function in your theme:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $logo_path = '/' . drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/logos/';
  // Alter logo under some conditions
  if ($first_condition) {
    $variables['logo'] = $logo_path . 'logo1.png';
  } elseif ($second_condition) {
    $variables['logo'] = $logo_path . 'logo2.png';
  } elseif ($third_condition) {
    // Hide logo. Your page.tpl.php must contain 
    // something like <?php if ($logo): ?>
    $variables['logo'] = null;
  }
  // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "standard" way for printing logo is printing `$logo` variable from `page.tpl.php` template. But you don't have to do it that way at all.

I.e. you can add your php code which will alter logo html code the way you like.

Or, you can place logo html inside static blocks and set for every block on what pages should it appear (in block settings). And of course create "logo" region for your theme.

Answer (score -1):

For Drupal 10

```
function yortheme_theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

   $variables['logo'] = theme_get_setting('logo.url');

}
```

And in page.html.twig

```
<img src="{{ logo }}" >
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_maintenance_page/10

Comment: This is part code-only and part link-only. You may want to improve your answer by [edit]ing according to [answer].